# Form submission field not available in form action

Tags: views, 9, actions

I have the following form submission handler.

```php
function mymod_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $ka_selected = $form_state->getValue('ka_types');
  \Drupal::state()->set('ka_types', $ka_selected);
  return $ka_selected;
}
```

It returns the *ka_types* field value. I want to use `$ka_selected` in custom action code.

```php
public function execute(ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL) {
    //Read all the fields from entity
    $comment = $entity->get('comment_body')->getValue();
    $file_uri = file_create_url($entity->field_attachment->entity->getFileUri());
    $file_name = $entity->field_attachment->entity->getFileName();
    $ka = $entity->ka_selected->entity->getValue(); **//error thrown here**
    dd($ka);
}
```

I am able to read other view entities but not just this field.

How can I use the value of `$ka_selected` in my custom action?

Comment: Could you please clarify - I think there's no hook_form_submit in Drupal 9? And why do you store your value in a state and later expect it in the entity?

Comment: Drupal 9 has hook_form_submit and I can dump the selected values there perfectly. Just those values are not getting passed on to the execute method in the custom action

Comment: Drupal has never used [`hook_form_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/9.1.x/search/hook_submit_form). A form submission handler isn't a hook. What stored in a form element isn't necessarily an entity field. I could use add a form element in an entity edit form and its value won't end in an entity field.

Comment: Also, a form submission handler doesn't return any value. Even if it were to return a value, that value would be discarded from Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I am able to figure out the answer from the below link: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2021-07-04/read-view-row-entities-and-create-a#comment-14154305

```
public function execute(ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL) {
    //Read all the fields from entity
    $comment = $entity->get('comment_body')->getValue();
    $file_uri = file_create_url($entity->field_attachment->entity->getFileUri());
    $file_name = $entity->field_attachment->entity->getFileName();
    $ka = \Drupal::state()->get('ka_types');
    dd($ka);
}
```